# How do I send Arabic and other RTL languages in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey, arabic, right-to-left

Is there a way to make Send or SendInput output Arabic text from Right to Left?
I checked around but was unable to find a satisfactory solution to the problem.

Comment: I thought `send` always sent in chronological order? Why would that display in the wrong directionality?

Comment: Why don't you try it: وقال ياقوت: كان أبوه من أصحاب الكسائي، عالمًا بالعربية, واللغة, والشعر, وكان يعقوب -يعني ابن السِّكِّيْتِ- يؤدب الصبيان مع أبيه في درب القنطرة بمدينة السلام، حتى احتاج إلى الكسب، فأقبل على تعلم النحو من البصريين والكوفيين، فأخذ عن أبي عمرو الشيباني، والفراء، وابن الأعرابي، والأثرم، وروى عن الأصمعي، وأبي عبيدة. وأخذ عنه أبو سعيد السكري، وأبو عكرمة الضبي، ومحمد بن الفرج المقرئ، ومحمد بن عجلان الأخباري، وميمون بن هرون الكاتب، وغيرهم, وكان عالِمًا بالقرآن, ونحو الكوفيين، ومن أعلم الناس باللغة, والشعر، رواية, ثقة, ولم يكن بعد ابن الأعرابي مثله

Comment: As you can see, the last line is to the left whereas it should be to the right. Copy it to your clipboard and then output it with Send, you will see it will always stay at the left.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Did you try it?

Comment: You could always have a set number of characters/words on a line, and if it does not fill the line you could frontfill with spaces.

Comment: This could be a windows problem. I had the problem that I copied text via the clipboard in Windows from Arabic documents into other applications which then paste mirrored lines. You can try to write the clipboard content into a file with the fileappend command. I expect that it is already incorrect in the clipboard. If this is the case, it is trivial (but a lot of work) to create you own Ctrl-c hotkey that corrects the clipboard whenever certain applications are in focus.

Comment: Send/SendInput sends keystrokes (or in special cases, messages containing character codes) in the order given in the string, first to last.  Since I know nothing about RTL text, I can't say how the order of characters in memory relates to how the string displays.  In any case, Send/SendInput and the Windows API functions on which they rely do not offer any options relating to RTL text.  -- An idea: if the text comes out in reverse order, try reversing the string you send.

Comment: The text doesn't come out in reverse as in mirror writing. You can still read the sentence. Here is an example in the English language:....................................................................This is an example  ............................................................................This is anotherexample...............................................................................................................................

Comment: It is difficult to make it appear nicely. The first example cam out nicely. The second one failed because you can only edit comments for 5 minute. Look at the first example. That is how an english sentence would output in RTL mode. Instead of it being all the way at the left, it is at the right. It is annoying because it breaks convention. But you can still read it. The same for Arabic when output in LTR orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a unicode version of autohotkey.  I also suggest you use Autohotkey_L.

http://l.autohotkey.net/